# Rails 3.1 Asset pipeline - IE not loading all stylesheets in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Testing my site in Internet Explorer (testing with IE 9 at the moment) I saw many things wrong but quite a few things that I thought shouldn't be wrong.

It turns out that IE isn't applying all the stylesheets in development mode (verified by adding a `body { border: 10px solid blue; }` rule to one of the stylesheets).

I've opened up the development tools and done network capturing and it reports they're all loaded (result: 304).

I've tried running the server both through Webrick & thin.

Only thing I can think is it's just too many stylesheets for IE to cope with. The only way I've got it to work is by pre-compiling the assets and running the server in production mode. But this is of course far from ideal.

Answer (score 9):

Yuck IE imposes a 31 stylesheet limit: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ad1b6e88-bbfa-4cc4-9e95-3889b82a7c1d/

The only way I found around this in development is to change my settings to:

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.debug = false
```

Comment: That is ridiculous! Why should be there such a limit? Are we back in days where 640 kb would be enough?

Answer (score 2):

Certain comments inside css files can also prevent them from loading in IE6 and IE7  (IE8 seems ok).
Comments with quotes, like for a font style, will prevent it from loading.

A comment such as the one below, *with quotes inside*, will prevent the file from loading:

```
/* ‘Lucida Sans Unicode’ */
```